# Create word documents from excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an excel sheet that lists shipping data in columns, e.g. shipment number, date, amount, weight etc.
I have a set payment term when the invoice for each shipment can be created.

I have found a way to create a sub-procedure in VBA that creates a Word document. However, I am having difficulties to format the Word document in the way that I want it.

The sub procedure I am working with is from a tutorial
(https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-word-documents-within-excel-vba-d13333jl)

Using this method, I would need to tediously format the invoice (the word document I want to create automatically from the excel sheet).

Is there a way to create a word form as a docx file, which I can reference using a macro to fill in fields with the data in a given line (with the shipping information).

In my head, I have my excel file that shows when a shipment can be invoiced, then there is an object with a macro linked to it which will use the data from the selected line and fill it in the word form.

Is this possible?
The main document that will be used is the excel sheet. So ideally, the last cell of a line has a button or link that can be pressed that generates the invoice with the data of the line in which the pressed button/link is located.

Comment: You can create a pre-formatted Word template and populate it from Excel.

Comment: Have you looked into using a Word template (.DOTX) and then the Excel can update the template fields?

Comment: Word mail merge is a good feature for your question. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Choose an account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461) OR https://helpdesk.concord.edu/kb/article/122-how-to-do-a-mail-merge-in-word-using-an-excel-spreadsheet/

Comment: See my **Microsoft Word Catalogue/Directory Mailmerge Tutorial** page, at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html